# Can't clone a gitlab repo with SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've generated public/private key pair with ssh-keygen :

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "git@gitlab.xxx"
```

I've added the contents of the public key with .pub extension in the "deploy keys" section of gitlab repo and ensured it was "enabled".

I've also added it to my account settings under "SSH keys".

When I try to clone the repo with a ssh git clone :

```
git clone git@gitlab.xxx:path/to/repo.git
```

It still requests a password and when I input the passphrase it says "Permission denied".
I also tried without passphrase after re-generating a key without passphrase.

Same thing when I try to specify a key :

```
git clone git@gitlab.xxx:path/to/repo.git --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i /path/to/private_key"
```

with `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.xxx -i /path/to/private_key` it says :

```
debug1: Offering ED25519 public key: /path/to/private_key"
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Try debugging it via `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.xxx` (if the issue is with authentication then git isn't necessary for debugging, as the issues will be the same without it).

Comment: Please don't dump logs like this in the comments, instead [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: ok, sorry, done

Comment: Do you have write permission to that repository?
Are you able to access it from Gitlab UI?

Comment: I have my own user to push to the repository, and as I said I've added the contents of the public key with .pub extension in the "deploy keys" section of gitlab repo and ensured it was "enabled" which means I'm able to access it from Gitlab UI

Comment: The deploy key section of the repo is meant for read-only keys. Remove it from there and add it to your user account (in the settings).

Comment: Does it mean the user of the key must match the gitlab account that holds the key ? I usually just use 'git' as key user.

Comment: quoted from GitLab : "Deploy keys allow read-only or read-write (if enabled) access to your repository"

Comment: I still can't clone this repo with SSH. On which Gitlab account should the ssh key be registered ?

Comment: It should be on your account. The username `git` doesn't change; that's how your request gets to GitLab instead of to a shell account.

Comment: I have the same issue on ubuntu, `debug3: receive packet: type 51` - i just added the ssh key to my gitlab users ssh kys, the hash is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues with the Gitlab server:

1. It didn't support ed25519, it supported only rsa
2. It refused git as a user, it expected some service account name instead

```
git clone svcaccnt@gitlab.xxx:path/to/repo.git --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i /path/to/private_key"
```